# $p(x).y''+p'(x).y'+\frac{1}{p(x)}.y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a general solution I can give to the differential equation $\; p(x).y''+p'(x).y'+\frac{1}{p(x)}.y=0\;$ (the function $p(x)$ wasn't given) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\; p(x).y''+p'(x).y'+\frac{1}{p(x)}.y=0\;$$
You can easily reduce the order:
$$(p(x).y')'=-\frac{1}{p(x)}.y$$
$$p(x)y'(p(x).y')'=-y'y$$
Integrate.
$$p^2(x)y'^2=- {y^2}+C$$
This differential equation is separable.

Comment: How to make this separation? The separable differential equations I have already solved were with $y'$ and not $(y')^2$.

Comment: @RebecaLieYatsuzukaSilva  well you have $y'P(x)=\pm \sqrt {C-y^2}$ then $$\int \frac {dy}{\sqrt {C-y^2}}=\pm \int \dfrac {dx}{P(x)}$$